# Creating reports: MongoDB + .Net Win Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, reporting-services, mongodb

As I am working on `.Net windows form` application, we're using `MongoDB` for back-end data storage.

As the matter of business reports (Just like we're developing reports with Crystal report), I would like to know that `can we create business reports with MongoDB`??

As the reports are the very critical part of our application, I must have to create `reports using MongoDB`.

Could anybody please let me know that How would I create `reports with the use of MongoDB`? OR please let me know the other ways to do this.

Please let me know if this could be done via any service or component for .Net Win forms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any tool for building business reports with MongoDB. Reports with mongodb is  difficult task, because you need to load many documents and build reports yourself on the client side.

*So, i see two ways to do reports with mongodb*:
**1.** Load all documents that need for report and build it at the client side.
**2.** Create separate document for each report and build this report documents during application work(you can use some kind of queue and build reports async). So, in this case you will need just display documents from collection, but you need care about report documents inserts/updates.

If your system have many reports and reports main part of application, probably better to use sql database(or even both mongodb(for application) and sql(for reports)).

Answer (score 1):

I think that document databases force consumers to think about data warehousing, and this is a good thing.  Too often report developers rely on the transactional schema for reporting, and end up writing inefficient reports that are difficult to maintain.

I think you should have the data from mongo dump into a relational store that makes sense as a data warehouse.  Use that for reporting.